# duplicate entry in localstorage - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, duplicates, local-storage

I'm attempting to build a simple address book app using a more OOP approach.

Currently it adds to localStorage without problem; but the next task I wanted to accomplish was a function that displays the Key => value pairs within the HTML. I'm stuck at the first hurdle.

When I call the `displayContacts()` function on the click event, it is creating another empty object within the LocalStorage. Every time I reload the page and click the 'find' button (and assuming no additional information has been added to the form), a new entry will be added to localStorage such as:

> {"first_name":"","last_name":"","email":"","telephone":""}

Thanks in advance

< !-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```js
 var addressBook = {

    people : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts')) || [],


    cacheDom : function(){
        this.$parent = $('.address_book');
        this.$display = $('.find_contacts');
    },

    bindEvent : function(){
        this.$parent.on('submit', this.getFormData.bind(this)); 
        this.$display.on('click', this.displayContacts.bind(this));

    },

    getStorage : function(param){
        return localStorage.getItem(); 
    },

    setStorage : function(){
        var storage = localStorage.getItem("contacts");
                localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(this.people));

            },

    displayContacts : function(){
            var contacts = this.people;
            console.log(contacts);

    },

    getFormData : function(e){
        var contacts = {};
        var target = e.target.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < target; i++){
            if(e.target[i].nodeName === "INPUT"){
                contacts[e.target[i].name] = e.target[i].value;
                /*console.log(contacts);*/
            }
        }

        this.people.push(contacts);
        this.setStorage();


        return false;
    },




    render: function(){

    },

    init : function(){
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvent();
        this.setStorage();
    }
}

addressBook.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-4 input_field">

            <form class="address_book" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control first_name" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Telephone</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Phone Number" name="telephone">
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit_to_storage">Submit</button>
                <button type="edit" class="btn btn-default submit_to_storage">edit</button>
                <button type="delete" class="btn btn-default submit_to_storage">delete</button>
                <button type="find" class="btn btn-default find_contacts">find</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-push-10 output">

        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/localStorage.class.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is of type `find`

```
<button type="find" class="btn btn-default find_contacts">
```

This is not a valid type, and instead the button goes back to the default type, which is `submit`.

A `submit` button inside a form, submits the form, so not only are you calling the `click` handler on the button, but the `submit` handler for the form as well, which inserts into localStorage.

This is why, when you click the button it inserts in to localStorage.
To fix the issue, add a type of `button` to all the buttons that aren't supposed to submit the form.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit_to_storage">Submit</button>
<button type="edit" class="btn btn-default submit_to_storage">edit</button>
<button type="delete" class="btn btn-default submit_to_storage">delete</button>
<button type="find" class="btn btn-default find_contacts">find</button>
```

The only valid types for a button are

- submit
- reset
- button